# Entity Manager read old values even if locking with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic, java-ee-7, jta

I'm in the following scenario. Handling message inside an MDB, container managed transaction. MDB implements MessageListenerer interface so when a message is received it gets invoked (onMessage method).
The message contains an object with an amount. I need to sum that amount to the one inside the database. So inside the onMessage method I invoke my business logic that query the database by doing :

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
em.joinTransaction();
MyObject myObject = em.find(MyObject.class, key, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
em.refresh(myObject, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

As far as I know the second row (em.joinTransaction()) should not be needed (since the persistence context is created inside the JTA transaction....anyway this is not working because when I run a load test I get the wrong sum.
The application is deployed on weblogic 12.
By logging "myObject" I can see that different thread sometimes find to have the same value while I was expecting the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, to wait read outside of the transaction.

The action I'm performing on "myObject" is retrieving an integer, make a sum with an input value and then update the entity on the DB.
What I find is that the sum has not the expected value (i.e. the sum of the values inside the inbound jms messages).
Maybe the transaction is somehow shared among several thread? IMHO it makes no sense for an APP server to do that and, as far as I know, this is not the default behaviour of the weblogic JTA transaction manager.

EDIT: The database is oracle Enterprise Edition

Comment: You didn't mention your DB though, so maybe it doesn't support locks. If you have a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock on an object/row, it will prevent any other transaction writing to that row (or object changes getting persisted to it during a flush/commit). How that works for other threads trying to read the value depends on your database though, and I don't know how it would factor into your issue - nothing should be able to change values on you once you have that lock (again depending on your DB config). So what are you seeing really? You should be able to test your assumptions with a debugger

Comment: I added a few details, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Did you try debugging? Try turning on SQL logging, but I suspect you are expecting the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock to prevent other threads from seeing the current value while the lock is held, when all it guarantees is that no one else can change the value out from under the lock. If you want to prevent reads when this lock is held, you'd want to run all your queries with the PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock, so they can obtain the lock (and release it asap!), but the overhead is why pessimistic locking is frowned upon.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now. Running all my queries with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock. Nevertheless a few threads reads the same value and, of course, collision in the update happens (so the expected value is never matched)

Comment: Then you will have to look at how you are demarcating your transactions, as JPA will (turn on SQL logging to verify) issue a 'select .. for update' statement to the database that holds the lock until it is released (transaction commit/rollback). Common mistakes are to assume it is held longer than it is - if calling a transactional service that issues a find, it might be in its own separate transaction that is released immediately before the method returns. Logging within Weblogic will show its transaction handling as well, allowing you to line up the transactions, sql and your expectations